# Export to PDF file

Tags: teechart

I am evaluating Teechart 4.1.2012.2287 and I have a problem with the export to PDF function.
My project is written in VS2010, using VB.Net and framework 4.0, and I have Adobe Reader 9.4.7 on my PC.

When I try to open a PDF generated by TChart it says there is an error with the file.
I also get this problem using your Example application.

Is there a version requirment for the Reader?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is a bug. I get this error message:

> An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page
>   correctly. Please contact the person who created the PDF document to
>   correct the problem.

Do you get the same? Anyway, I added the issue (TF02016129) to the bug list to be investigated.

Comment: You should also look at your Excel export filter, when I try and open one of the generated files in Excel 2007 I get the following message:

The file that you are trying to open,"******.xls", is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?

If you do open the file it does go into Excel, but the meesage would not look very good if we used the filter.

Comment: @Ross Yes, this is a known issue which should be addressed.